# Where can I ask: Lotus Notes 8.5 Not Supporting Digital Badging

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have the following question that I want to ask. I think it is off-topic for main. Where can I ask this question:

> I have recently taken (and passed) my SAS Global Certification exam. SAS offers some downloadable watermarks for business cards and resumes, but recently they have incorporated digital badges from Acclaim. The digital badges look great, and are interactive when used in a signature. I can use this digital badge flawlessly in my gmail account, but in the office I have Lotus Notes 8.5
>
> The only way I am able to show my credential is using an image (which looks very poor) in this version of Lotus Notes, and is not clickable.
>
> Does Lotus Notes 8.5 not support the full use of digital badging/hyperlink imaging?

Is Super User a site that will fit?

Comment: Ok...I originally asked the question on stack overflow...and I was only following the directions from the commenter...suppose I will continue to surf the endless net...

Comment: @SMW they did not propose to post the same question verbatim as you did there. Just tagging it with `site-recommendation` does not really help, rene's edit does. I have retracted the down- and closevote in the meantime.

Comment: Sure [meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) and [help] are great places to start and we do allow site-recommemdations but you have to follow the guidance given in the tag-info: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/site-recommendation/info

Comment: Ok...will take to time to read/follow the guidelines. Thanks for the assistance/guidance.

Comment: So... after wading through that, I think you're trying to ask if lotus notes supports ... email signatures containing hyperlinks?  Is that correct?  Because if that's what you want to ask, you should probably ask that.

Comment: @will- your comment is partially correct, as I want to know if lotus knows specifically supports the digital badges issued by Acclaim. Other than that, your right... Guess I should just ask that question...

Answer (score 3):

You can post this question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lotus-notes) using at least the [lotus-notes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lotus-notes) tag.

I'm not saying there is or isn't anything wrong with your question, but make sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).